# Liquibase： How does it know that the database has changed (not in changelog)?

Tags: liquibase

How does Liquibase know that the database has changed (not in changelog).

What commands do you use to do this?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for. Please edit you question and try to make it more clear.

Comment: Perhaps describe a set of steps you are taking leading up the the question.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: you can look at the log when launching the command.

The liquibase principe is to be transparent whenever a modification is done/necessary to your database schema.

You can play with tags to achieve that but it's a misunderstading in my mind.